# jQuery animation Complete fires before event is complete

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jzhang172/mofnf7ua/1/

It may just be lag on my screen, but it seems that Complete fires before my animate finishes.  Is there an issue with my code and if so, how can I correct it so I can achieve the desired result?

```js
$(function(){

$(".hey").click(function(){ 
     var height=$(".two").height(); 

     console.log(height);
     if (height >400){
         $(".two").animate({
               height:"0px",
               opacity:0
          },
          {
            duration:1000,
            complete:function(){
            alert('hey');
           }
         });
     }//ifstatement end
     else {
         $(".two").animate({
            height:"500px",
           opacity:1
         });
   }
 });//clickfunction end
});//function end
```

```css
.hey{
  background:blue;
  height:50px;
  width:50px;
  transition:1s;
   
}
.two{
  background:red;
    height:500px;
  width:500px;
  transition:1s;
}
.no{
    opacity:1;
display:block;
  transition:1s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hey"></div>

<div class="hey two" id="two">fffffffff</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for this is the CSS you added `transition:1s;`. If you remove that it will be working fine.

The [animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) method performs a custom animation of a set of CSS properties.
This method changes an element from one state to another with CSS styles. The CSS property value is changed gradually, to create an animated effect.

> Default speed of the animation value is 400 milliseconds.

If you want to give a spped for animation you can give it via jQuery `animate()` itself.

**Working Demo**

```js
$(function() {

  $(".hey").click(function() {
    var height = $(".two").height();

    console.log(height);
    if (height > 400) {
      $(".two").animate({
        height: "0px",
        opacity: 0
      }, {
        duration: 1000,
        complete: function() {
          alert('hey');
        }
      });
    } //ifstatement end
    else {
      $(".two").animate({
        height: "500px",
        opacity: 1


      });
    }
  }); //clickfunction end


}); //function end
```

```css
.hey {
  background: blue;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  //transition: 1s;

}
.two {
  background: red;
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  // transition: 1s;

}
.no {
  opacity: 1;
  display: block;
  transition: 1s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hey"></div>

<div class="hey two" id="two">fffffffff</div>
```

Comment: I am working on it :). Will edit the answer and make it better